# 'useNavigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i am trying to use the `useNavigate` in my js page. here's how I am trying to use it:

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/auth";
import * as routes from '../routes';
import './checkout.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MyGifSpinner from './manageSubSpinner';
import './manageSubSpinner.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import myGif from '../pages/spinner';
import myGifSpinner from './manageSubSpinner';
import { doSignOut } from '../models/AuthorizationHome';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';


const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const app = firebase.app();


export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
  const navigate = useNavigate();

      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
      if (user == null) {
        navigate('/clients')
      }

  console.log(user)
 

  if (activtyStatus == "canceled") {
    console.log("sub is cancelled")
    //live price
    price = 'price_1IfmDsKDPaWWeL1ywjMTGarh'
    

  }
  
  console.log("activity status is: " + activtyStatus)

 


      const checkoutSessionRef = await firestore
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
        price: price,
        success_url: "http://localhost:3000/clients",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/signin",
    });

    
      // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
            checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(function (snap) {
              const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
              if (error) {
              console.log(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
              return;
            }
            if (sessionId) {
             
            const stripe = window.Stripe('pk');
            console.log("going to stripe: ")
           console.log("line 116 checkout.js")
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: sessionId})
            console.log("logged stripe")
            
          }
      });
    }
```

but I am getting that error still. I am on react-router-dom version 5.2.0, and react version 17.0.2. Please help :(

Answer (score 4):

`useNavigate` is a new hook in v6 that replaces the `useHistory` hook.

[React Router v6 Preview](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/)

Since you are still in v5 then you should import and use the `useHistory` hook to issue imperative navigation.

[React Router v5 Hooks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();

const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

useEffect(() => {
  if (!user) {
    history.push('/clients');
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: i Also tried what you had above, and unfortunately it gave me this error: `Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.` which is weird. I don't think I need to export it

Comment: @gianluca I can tell you for a fact that [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) is exported from `react-router-dom` v5.2.0. Are you absolutely sure that is the version you have installed?

Comment: yes. I ran this command in my cli `npm view react-router-dom version`, and it returned `5.2.0`

Comment: @gianluca Try blowing away your `node_modules` directory and rerunning `npm install` to reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately same thing. I uninstalled and then reinstalled. I am so weirded out by how this is happening

Comment: @gianluca Peculiar indeed. At this point all I can really offer is to try and reduce the complexity of this component to something simple that renders without error and incrementally add pieces back in until you find the offending import or line of code that breaks the `react-router-dom` import. Can you try to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue we can examine and debug live?

Comment: I could create a running sandbox, but I'm not sure how haha. never done it before.  Could you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231632/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-gianluca).